# continuity of $J(r,y) = |S^{n-1}|^{-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |r \omega - y|^{2-n} \text{d} \omega$

Tags: analysis, potential-theory

In a proof I'm trying to understand the continuity of this function is just being assumed and I'm a little stuck trying to show why.
This function is defined on $ \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $ with r the radius and y an element of $ \mathbb{R}^n $

Origin: Analysis by Elliott H. Lieb, Theorem 9.7

Comment: What did you try, to prove this continuity? Maybe there are relevant theorems in the earlier pages of the book.

Comment: the integral is not finite over $\mathbb{R}^n$ .. try using polar coordinates after translating with $y/r$.

Comment: I think $J$ is intended to be a kernel that one convolves with nice functions.  It reminds me a little to the Hilbert transform.

Comment: I have no clue where to start with proving it. I don't know how to use polar coordinates, nor was there any relevant Theorem, or it would have been referenced I think. This whole proof is a little bit out of my league since I'm only in my 2. year of mathematics, but I still want to understand it properly.